# Caching the data from database in mobile application, using doctrine2

Tags: mysql, database, caching, doctrine-orm, memcached

when the user buys some car manuals in application, he can able to use them without network

so I want to cache the manuals he purchased, I want step by step method to cache the database

```
    $memcache = new Memcache();
    $memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);
    $servers = array(
            'host'       => 'memcache_host',
            'port'       => 11211,
            'persistent' => true
    );


    $cacheDriver = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcacheCache(
                array(
                        'servers' => $servers,
                        'compression' => false
        )
    );
    $cacheDriver->setMemcache($memcache);
    $cacheDriver->save('cache_id', 'my_data');
```

I just want to know how does the my_data and id works ?

Comment: What application ? Mobile application ? Web application ? Your question is way to generic and quite impossible to answer here.

Comment: its mobile application and I ve added code to use the Memcache cache driver from the link http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/caching.html#memcache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memcached and all the other cache providers included with Doctrine 2 are server side caching mechanisms. Meaning that regardless of the users context, connectivity is required.

If you want to allow your user to access data from your application while offline, you will need to use something like HTML5 local storage, you can check out [nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-learning-about-html5-local-storage/) for a quick video intro to using it.

Comment: I have done Cache manifest for the UI files, all I need is to cache the database result in the mobile applicatin